# How to ignore wwwroot/lib in TFS 2013 using VS15RC and ASP.NET5?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

### Problem

By accident, wwwroot/lib was added to our TFS13 server when we created an ASP.NET5 application.

Realizing what happened, we deleted it from the solution and committed the change. This removed the wwwroot/lib directory from TFS13 server. Yay! Right? Well, we then put .tfignore in our project root file `DemoApp/src/DemoApp/.tfignore`. In this file we added the line `wwwroot\lib`.

However, everytime we make a change to the application, it wants to add `wwwroot\lib` back to TFS. It's really frustrating because we have more the location of .tfignore around. We have made our workspace local and tried the pending changes trick to autogenerate a tfingore file according to msdn documents.

In short, `wwwroot\lib` keeps trying to come back with more tenacity than Michael Myers in Halloween. If anyone else has run into this problem, please let us know. We have tried bing, google-fu, stackoverflow, and some .NET experts. This stumped all of us.

Comment: I ran into the same exact issue, please let me know if you were able to fix this. It's incredibly frustrating!

Comment: I have noted that Microsoft has moved to github on ASP.NET5. Our team is currently building a new TFS server that will use git. We are hopeful that using git rather than 'tfs' will resolve this issue. Why? Because .gitignore handles this.

Comment: Try updating your .tfignore file to `wwwroot\lib\*` adding the  **\\***. The location of your .tfignore is important so you will need the relative path to your `wwwroot\lib` folder from the location of the .tfignore file

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Your tfignore should work once the aspnet team addresses it.

See here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18